# Запятая в сложноподчиненном предложении (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Подскажите, будьте добры, в каком месте стоит поставить запятую: "Я знаю(,) лишь(,) что все мы выбрались оттуда".

Answer (score 1):

***Я знаю лишь (то), что все мы выбрались оттуда.***

Пояснение

1. Это СПП с придаточным **изъяснительным**, частица ***лишь*** относится к пропущенному указательному слову ***то***, а  не к подчинительному союзу.
2. У Розенталя есть правило, согласно которому **частица может относиться к подчинительному союзу**, но это касается предложений другого вида (не изъяснительных).

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

6. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят усилительные частицы *как раз, только, лишь, исключительно* и т. п., то перед ними ставится запятая (вопреки интонации, так как при чтении пауза перед ними не делается): *Катя вышла из столовой, **как раз когда** мы шагнули друг к другу через какие-то чемоданы* (Кав.); *Я эту работу выполню, **только если** буду свободен* (ср.: *…если только буду свободен*); *Он приехал, **исключительно чтобы** помочь мне.*